# File isn't removed using remove() function in c

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++-2005

I have written a c++ library to remove a file using `remove` function in `Visual C++ 2005`. But it doesn't remove the file. How can I resolve this problem?

The sample code is given below:

```
FILE *fp;
char temp[10000];
char *filename;

GetCurrentDirectoryA(10000,temp);
strcat(temp,"\\temp.png");

filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(temp));
memset(filename,'\0',strlen(temp));
strcpy(filename,temp);

if(png == NULL)
    return LS_ARGUMENT_NULL;

fp = fopen(filename,"wb");
fwrite(png,sizeof(unsigned char),pngLength,fp);
fclose(fp);

result = remove(filename);
```

Comment: For one, the `filename` buffer is one character too short. You haven't left space for a null terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring other parts, I think you should allocate one more character:

```
filename = (char*)malloc(strlen(temp)+1); // I added a +1 for last '\0'
// memset(filename,'\0',strlen(temp));    // You dont need this
strcpy(filename, temp);
```

If you need to remove a file from current directory just the name is enough:

```
remove("temp.png");
```

Get rid of those `GetCurrentDirectoryA` and related codes.

Answer (score 2):

1)    char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
Concatenate strings
 Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

So u need not need to append NULL \0 character

2) For remove to work, u need to have file permission. Check it.

3) Check for errors and print error using strerror(errno)

Also ur code doesn't seem to chek if fopen is successful

```
if( remove( "myfile.txt" ) != 0 )
perror( "Error deleting file" );
 else
puts( "File successfully deleted" );
return 0;
```

Comment: A nitpick: `\0` is `NUL` although it's call null-terminator; `NULL` is something different, that's why I prefer to use 0-/zero-terminator. Anyway: +1

Answer (score 0):

Theres no point in making it *windows only* by using `GetCurrentDirectory`.

Heres a fancy cross-platform version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    char file[1024];
    char buffer[2048];

    // Get file name.
    std::cout << "Enter name of file to create: ";
    std::cin >> file;

    // Append .txt to file.
    sprintf(file, "%s.txt", file);

    // Create it.
    std::cout << "* Creating file: " << file << std::endl;
    std::ofstream out(file);

    // Write in it.
    std::cout << "Write in the file: (CTRL+Z to stop)" << std::endl;
    while (std::cin >> buffer)
    {
        out << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    // Close it.
    out.close();

    // Delete it.
    std::cout << "* Deleting file: " << file << std::endl;
    if (remove(file) != 0) std::cerr << "* Couldn't remove the file. Does the program have the required permissions?" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your posting does not seem to answer the OP's question.

Comment: @alk The fact that filename was one char short and as a result wasn't null terminated was already covered in a comment. I merely just got together a small version of how he should properly delete the file. More importantly I wanted to point out the fact that using a absolute path wasn't necessary for `remove()`.

Comment: Why `sprintf` in C++ code; and why not `ostringstream` or `string`? `sprint` is notorious and usually on a banned function list. `string{stream}` is the C++ way and its not dangerous.